# How to test if PrintWriter / OutputStreamWriter / BufferedWriter / OutputStream is working?

Tags: java

With terminal I type `chiplotle` and after that I type `11`.
This is how the terminal looks after that:
[image]

I want to do the same thing in java but i'm stuck with the eleven options part.
I know when it happens and I print a `11` but nothing happens after that.

It might be in this part.

```
if (line.equals("[11] Plotter")) {
  System.out.println("---!!!---"); // it does print this!
  pw.println("11"); // tried multiple things
  pw.println("or give me at least an error...");
}
```

But i'm afraid my print writer is wrong. How can I test this?

```
import java.io.*;


public class ExecTest {

    ChiplotleInputStream chiplotleInputStream;
    ChiplotleErrorStream chiplotleErrorStream;

    PrintWriter pw;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ExecTest().setup();

    }


    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public void setup() {

        try {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();

            Process process = runTime.exec("chiplotle");

            chiplotleInputStream = new ChiplotleInputStream(process);
            chiplotleErrorStream = new ChiplotleErrorStream(process);

            OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

            new Thread(chiplotleInputStream).start();
            new Thread(chiplotleErrorStream).start();


//            process.destroy();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public class ChiplotleInputStream implements Runnable {

        BufferedReader in;

        public ChiplotleInputStream(Process process) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            String line;

            try {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    System.out.println(line);

                    if (line.equals("[11] Plotter")) {
                        System.out.println("---!!!---"); // it does print this!
                        pw.println("11\r\n"); // tried multiple things
                        pw.println("or give me at least an error...");
                    }


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


     // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


     public class ChiplotleErrorStream implements Runnable {

         BufferedReader in;

         public ChiplotleErrorStream(Process process) {
             in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
         }

         @Override
         public void run() {

             String line;

             try {
                 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                     System.out.println(line);
                 }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

         }
     }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


}
```

Comment: Sigh. Very much like the previous question. Don't expect the program to operate the same way when it has its input and output redirected (to streams in Java) and when it runs in interactive mode. Send the input first.

Comment: Does this mean it's also not possible to have any input from the user? For example choose which plotter he wants?

Comment: O yeah sending the input first doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the pw? Not sure why you're using a BufferedWriter AND a PrintWriter...

Comment: What ever you print into your `pw` is considered to be the input from the user. I'd suggest consulting the chiplotle documentation and/or forums for how to work with it in non-interactive mode, e.g. how to set a plotter. Test by creating a text file with all the commands you want to send, and running `chiplotle < file.txt`. When it works with a file, you can start playing with Java.

Comment: @Aify thank you so much! Finally a constructive comment. The flush() did the trick! I use BufferedWriter and PrintWriter cause it was suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926510/java-program-that-exec-commands-wont-continue/28926644#28926644 would you suggest something else?

Comment: If your println is working, why bother with the PrintWriter? You could just as easily call System.out.println([your stuff here]); and save yourself a ton of trouble. In other words, don't fix what's not broken - the other question can be solved solely by reading the input in another thread - the BW and the PW part is unnecessary, IMO.

Comment: System.out.println Does print in the console but it does not send the command to the program running it. Anyway, like you say, don't fix what's not broken :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flush()` the PrintWriter. When using the PW in conjunction with the BufferedWriter like you have done, you may need to flush the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the right answer without being real skeptic :)